# How to get the windows login user on asp web page?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, membership

I wonder if it is possible for an official way or hack to retrieve the windows login of the user currently logged on a asp web page with option "allow anonymous users" ? Or using imported windows dll perhaps ?

I know that normally with the "deny anonymous users" I can easily retrieve the login windows. But for some special reason I would like to retrieve the windows login and accept anonymous users. So that if the windows login is a user in my database I redirects to another web page.

I have ckecked that: (but windowsLogin == always empty)

**ASP- C#**

```
string windowsLogin = System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;
string windowsLogin = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
string windowsLogin = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.ToString();
string windowsLogin = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString();
```

**Web.config**

```
<authorization>
      <deny users ="?" /><!-- Deny acces to anonymous users-->
      <allow users ="*" /><!-- Allow acces to every users-->
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="./WebLogin.aspx" defaultUrl="./default.aspx" timeout="12" path="/" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" slidingExpiration="true"  />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP - its a .net question

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allow anonymous users, it seems, and you might want to try Windows authentication.

```
<authorization>
  <allow users ="*" /><!-- Allow acces to every user and do not deny anonymous -->
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

It seems [ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) have been depreciated for C# in some instances.

If so, you'll need to do it this way:

```
string login = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

If you really want to use ServerVariables, keep in mind they are **CaSe Sensitive** in C#. The correct casing is almost always *UPPER*, and here is the list of them:

[List of ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)